# solve this 8-puzzle

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, sliding-blocks

This quiz is about the 8-puzzle. It is a board with 9 fields. There are 8 tiles with numbers from one to eight. One field is empty. You can slide numbers around the board: But only numbers next to the empty field can be slid into the empty field:

```
1  2  3
4     5
6  7  8
```

You can slide the 2, 4, 7 and 5 into the middle.

The start position is this:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8
```

Your task is to give me the algorithm needed to get my puzzle back to the start position.

My puzzle is:

```
2  8  3
1  5  6
4  7
```

Hint:

> I needed eleven boards to create this pattern, including start and end state.

First solution wins.

Comment: More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle

Comment: So it doesn't have to be the shortest? Also how could you tell if we used computers or not.

Comment: He can't. He simply believes in our honesty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kinda easy to solve in my opinion (10 moves):

[image]

Comment: Rather 10 moves, no ?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer:

> 6-5-8-2-1-4-7-8-5-6

Comment: Please hide your answer, as I have done for you.